# Adjsting the height of component dynamically

Tags: lightning, javascript, css, html, uiscrollerwrapper

I have two child  component A and B inside a parent component stacked one after other.Component A is supposed to be static and does not contains scroll bar.How ever its height changes depends on screen size.Component B contains scroll bar and is supposed to occupy the remaining space on screen.
I have applied the scroll wrapper on B and it's Height is set to 43vh(for example).However since component A's height changes based on screen , some bootom part of component B goes out of applied height.
[image]
How am I supposed to calculate the remaining part of height after occupied by component A.

Comment: Could you incldue a minimal reproduceable code sample of what you have implemented so far? thanks